# New pop up in Visual Studio Code since update, can't get rid of it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since update, Visual Studio Code has had a really annoying new pop up tip that I can't get rid of. It autocompletes the word in a different way from the old pop up tips that I got rid of in settings.json. I've added everything I can find online to the settings.json file but it's still there. Please help as it's driving me mad, it keeps changing the words I'm writing. I've added a picture of it:

[picture of visual studio code demonstrating the pop up tip that autocompletes words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6gzO.jpg)

This is the settings.json script I have:

```
{
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": "never",
"editor.autoClosingOvertype": "never",
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
"html.autoClosingTags": false,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": false,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": false,
"editor.suggest.showMethods": false,
"editor.suggest.showOperators": false,
"editor.suggest.showSnippets": false,
"editor.suggest.showReferences": false,
"editor.suggest.showProperties": false,
"editor.suggest.showModules": false,
"editor.suggest.showInterfaces": false,
"editor.suggest.showIssues": false,
"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
"editor.suggest.showIcons": false,
"editor.suggest.showFunctions": false,
"editor.suggest.showInlineDetails": false,
"editor.suggest.showClasses": false,
"editor.suggest.showColors": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstants": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstructors": false,
"editor.suggest.showCustomcolors": false,
"editor.suggest.showDeprecated": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnumMembers": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnums": false,
"editor.suggest.showEvents": false,
"editor.suggest.showFields": false,
"editor.suggest.showFiles": false,
"editor.suggest.showFolders": false,
"editor.suggest.showStructs": false,
"editor.suggest.showTypeParameters": false,
"editor.suggest.showUnits": false,
"editor.suggest.showUsers": false,
"editor.suggest.showValues": false,
"editor.suggest.showWords": false,
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false,
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000,
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
```

}

Comment: what do you type with this suggestion box shown, you can exit a suggestion with `Esc`

Comment: Any variable name causes it to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. If I change to quickSuggestions to 10 million

```
"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 10000000,
```

it means it waits a long time before happening. So it is the quick suggestions that are the problem. I changed the above to:

```
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
```

and now it's gone. Finally. Phew.